# publishing a database from VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-express

i want to publish a database using visual studio to my SQL instance,
however i get this error
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
when i "select user_name" i get the 'guest' account in a VS query, i do get 'dbo' in SSMS
how can i change my account in VS to use dbo instead of guest?

I added my self to server roles in SSMS i still could not get it to release the DB

use master
exec sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame='mydomain\myUserName' , @rolename='sysadmin'
GO

Answer (score 0):

make sure of user executing the publishing by using 'select username()' first. If user is guest, run MS VS as admin !